# Allow navigation to a site that requires a certificate QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I added to my application qml a Web browser but I can not connect to a website which requires a certificate.
Because when I add the website I obtain a white page. 
Help me please.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean an HTTPS website?

Comment: no I can connect to secure websites, but I can't for secure website which requires a certificate. When I connect with the browser of PC I obtain "The site's security certificate is not trusted" but with the browser of my application I obtained a white page.

Answer (score 2):

To communicate with web site which uses untrusted certificates you should provide your own NetworkManagerFactory to QDeclarativeEngine as below. More over, this technique will help you to monitor what's going wrong with your networks requests in any other cases.

```
class WebViewNetworkManagerFactory
  : public QObject
  , public QDeclarativeNetworkAccessManagerFactory
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit WebViewNetworkManagerFactory(QObject *parent = 0)
    : QObject(parent)
  {}

public: // QDeclarativeNetworkAccessManagerFactory
  QNetworkAccessManager *create(QObject *parent) {
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkAccessManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(parent);
    connect(networkAccessManager, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)),
            this, SLOT(onSslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)));
    connect(networkAccessManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(onReplyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    return networkAccessManager;
  }

private slots:
  void onSslErrors(QNetworkReply *reply, const QList<QSslError> &errors) {
    qDebug("onSslErrors");
    reply->ignoreSslErrors(errors);
  }

  void onReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    Q_ASSERT(reply); if (!reply) return;
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
      return;
    }
    const int httpStatusCode = reply->attribute(
      QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
      qDebug(QString("Network error = %1, HTTP code = %2, error description = '%3'")
               .arg(reply->error())
               .arg(httpStatusCode)
               .arg(reply->errorString())
               .toAscii());
  }
};
```

Usage somewhere in your code, where you create a root DeclarativeView:

```
QDeclarativeView *buildRootView() {
  QScopedPointer<QDeclarativeView> view(new QDeclarativeView());
  QObject::connect(view->engine(), SIGNAL(quit()),
                   view.data(), SLOT(close()));
  view->engine()->setNetworkAccessManagerFactory(
    new WebViewNetworkManagerFactory(view.data()));
  // other initialization stuff...
  return view.take();
}
```